# how connect to a wireless network connection via command prompt in windows?

Tags: networking, batch-file, command-line

I searched a lot related to `netsh` and `ipconfig /renew` and `ipconfig /release`.

My idea is to write a batch file that would automatically connect to a particular wireless local area network using a network interface .

I tried using `ipconfig /renew release` ... but it cannot be used as  my intention is to keep the media in a disconnected state before running the batch file ..

any suggestions ?

Edit:

Narrowed it down to

```
connect name=Profile2 ssid=SSID2 interface="Wireless Network Connection"
```

Where do i find the "name" in network and sharing center?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What about:

```
netsh wlan connect=SSID
```

http://www.computing.net/answers/networking/wireless-connect-command-line/34771.html

Comment: Hi Peehaa thanks for  quick reply :) ... I tried that  too .. the same poster says that the  method has been lost and has been downgraded ...

Comment: @HelloWorld_Always: The poster says the reason the method got lost is because he downgraded his OS from Vista -> XP. So I don't know what clients you want to support with the batch file, but I you use >= Vista you should be ok. What error did you get when trying the method or are you on XP?

Comment: it workd .. sorry for accepting after a long time

Comment: @HelloWorld_Always: No problem. Glad I could resolve your issue. And thanks for accepting the answer so other users know it works :)

Answer (score 2):

Same as PeeHaa

```
Usage: connect [name=]<string> [[ssid=]<string>] [[interface=]<string>]
```

but Scott Hanselman provides [good information](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/HowToConnectToAWirelessWIFINetworkFromTheCommandLineInWindows7.aspx) on most netsh wlan commands.

```
D:\>netsh wlan

The following commands are available:

Commands in this context:
?              - Displays a list of commands.
add            - Adds a configuration entry to a table.
connect        - Connects to a wireless network.
delete         - Deletes a configuration entry from a table.
disconnect     - Disconnects from a wireless network.
dump           - Displays a configuration script.
export         - Saves WLAN profiles to XML files.
help           - Displays a list of commands.
refresh        - Refresh hosted network settings.
reportissues   - Generate WLAN smart trace report.
set            - Sets configuration information.
show           - Displays information.
start          - Start hosted network.
stop           - Stop hosted network.

To view help for a command, type the command, followed by a space, and then
 type ?.
```

Answer (score 1):

To disconnect from a wireless network

*netsh wlan disconnect interface="wireless adapter name"*

---

To connect to a wireless network

*netsh wlan connect name="wireless network profile name" ssid="As you known" interface="wireless adapter name"*

---

You can get profile name, interface name by

*netsh wlan show interface/profile*

---

You will need to create a profile for the wireless network first which you can do in "Wireless network management" under "Network and sharing center" in Control panel.